Conforming Another Noise Tool Terrain to Custom Plane Shape?
I'm using the “Another Noise Tool” addon in Blender to generate mountain terrains. However, it appears that this addon only creates square-shaped terrains. Is there a method to make the terrain conform to the contour of a specific plane?
I've attempted to use the Shrinkwrap modifier without success. My goal is to have the borders of the mountains smoothly adapt to the shape of a mesh or curve along the X and Y axes. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?


You could extrude the plane and use it in a boolean modifier with the intersect setting

@Cornivius this would create a rough cliff on the sides, and I want a smooth transition, like a real mountain

you could select the edges of that cliff going all around and use proportional editing to bring them down to the same level while smoothing the rest of the mountain. Aside from that I think you'd need something a lot more dedicated than a procedurally generated noise displacement. Like sculpting it by hand on sculpt mode or using weight paints to control a displacement modifier.


If you create a clouds texture and use a displacement modifier with it on a subdivided plane you'll get a similar result to what the addon does. But if you want that custom shape you'd have to paint it in weight paint mode.
Scaling the booleand piece down with proportional editing does give better results a lot faster, imo

